# When passing context to another class I get a Fatal Exception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Can someone tell me why this class returns a fatal exception when called in my main activity?

```
package com.b1ackjosh.kana;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SoundThread extends Thread  implements Runnable, OnCompletionListener       {

    Thread t = null;
    int place, lvl;
    boolean tStatus = false;
        Context context;

    SoundThread(int l, int p, Context c)  {
        p = place;
        c = context;
        l = lvl;
    };

    public void run() {

         MediaPlayer audioQuestion = MediaPlayer.create(context, QuestionArray.audioArray[lvl][place]);

         audioQuestion.setOnCompletionListener(this);
         audioQuestion.start();

    };

    public void pause() {
        tStatus = false;

        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t = null;
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

This is how I'm running it in my main activity:

```
public void playQuizAudio(final int i) {
    new SoundThread(lvl, i, this).start();
}
```

I just pass an integer to this method and every time I run it, my application fails and crashes to the home screen. It's annoying, but if i include the same code in my main activity it runs fine but I think I'm having some other threading issues which is why I choose to create a separate class to manage it. Also if I use a static link from the audio it also fails, so I know it has to be the context. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Also this is what I'm getting from LogCat:

```
04-12 03:52:43.981: E/AndroidRuntime(3129): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-98
04-12 03:52:43.981: E/AndroidRuntime(3129): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 03:52:43.981: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:731)
04-12 03:52:43.981: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at com.b1ackjosh.kana.SoundThread.run(SoundThread.java:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, you have:

```
SoundThread(int l, int p, Context c)  {
    p = place;
    c = context;
    l = lvl;
};
```

That's back to front! It should be:

```
SoundThread(int l, int p, Context c)  {
    place = p;
    context = c;
    lvl = l;
};
```

The compiler should have warned you on that, so please pay attention to it. Furthermore:

```
public class SoundThread extends Thread  implements Runnable
```

is redundant. Choose one or the other, and the advice is usually `Runnable`:

```
public class SoundThread implements Runnable
```

Comment: It didn't actually tell me that was a problem... which I find weird. Now I feel dumb lol. I've been staring at this crap for too long.

Comment: In short, The OP assigned a value to parameters rather than the fields. Good Catch!

Answer (score 1):

> **java.lang.NullPointerException** 04-12 03:52:43.981:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3129): at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:731) 04-12
>   03:52:43.981: E/AndroidRuntime(3129): at
>   com.b1ackjosh.kana.SoundThread.run(**SoundThread.java:23**)

You're getting a `NullPointerException` on the following line:

```
MediaPlayer audioQuestion = MediaPlayer.create(context, QuestionArray.audioArray[lvl][place]);
```

Assuming the `context`, `lvl` and `place` variables are all set correctly, the (static) field `QuestionArray.audioArray` is probably not initialized (hence `null`) when this line is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both you and ken were right but since ken was more specific I gave him the answer.

Comment: @b1ackjosh: All good, I upvoted his answer too, since he was spot on. :)